# Matrix dimensions must agree error while actually the same

Tags: image, matlab

I got an error message saying:

```
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in tankGame>exmRange (line 119)
    if (p1.dir == 'down') p1.value = imrotate(p1.oriValue, 180,'bilinear'); end
```

Yet I checked the size of `p1.value` and `p1.oriValue`, both of them are `32x32x3`. And if I delete this part the program runs perfectly.

I assume it's because `imrotate` somehow changed the dimension (although it shouldn't, for 180-degree square image rotation), so how can I fix it?

Comment: When you say that your program runs perfectly when you delete something, then are you concerned? (Perhaps you meant say is that when you deleted something, your code was able to execute but probably not with the results you want.) Okay let's pretend that this 32x32x3 matrix is some type of prism. It would be helpful to know how you want to rotate this prism. [Think about this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzD8c.png) of how you're rotating the image.

Comment: @KingDuken I mean if I don't rotate the image, everything is fine. The thing about rotating image is that I don't think there is more than 1 way to rotate, this is simply an image, not a plane in a 3D space...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is likely generating the error is `p1.dir == 'down'`. The `==` operator is an element-wise operator, it compares each of the characters in the two char vectors, yielding a boolean vector indicating which of the character pairs are equal. It is not doing a string comparison.

For example, if `p1.dir` is the char vector `'up`', then you are comparing a vector with 2 characters to one with 4 characters:

```matlab
'up'=='down'   % generates the error message "Matrix dimensions must agree."
'doom'=='down' % returns the logical array [true true false false]
```

Use `strcmp` to compare strings:

```matlab
if strcmp(p1.dir,'down')
   p1.value = imrotate(p1.oriValue, 180,'bilinear');
end
```

---

In newer versions of MATLAB (starting with R2016b) there is an actual `string` type (as opposed to the `char` vector that has always been called "string" in MATLAB). A `string` is created with double-quotes: `"down"` (as opposed to `'down'`, which is a `char` vector). For this new type, the `==` operator does do a string comparison. When applying the operator to a `string` an a `char` vector, the `char` is converted to a `string`. So another solution would be to do this:

```matlab
if p1.dir == "down"
   p1.value = imrotate(p1.oriValue, 180,'bilinear');
end
```

Comment: That is indeed the problem, Thank you. I think I might have adopted some bad habit with python.

Comment: @AmarthGûl: I forgot to say, in newer MATLAB's there's an actual `string` type. It is specified using double quotes. There the `==` operator does do string comparison. `p1.dir == "down"` will work as you expect, as `p1.dir` will be converted to a string type. But this does not work with Octave.